# A-Frame: how to simulate tracked controllers when developing on desktop?

Tags: aframe

My HTC Vive is set up in a different room to my developer workstation. When developing for [A-Frame](http://aframe.io), I understand I can: use my desktop monitor instead of a headset; use mouse dragging instead of motion controls; use WASD instead of room-scale tracking. However, what is the preferred way to simulate the tracked controllers?

For example, how can I move the cubes in this demo from my desktop: https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/tracked-controllers

Answer (score 2):

This is not yet released, but we're working on tools to be able to record camera and controllers, output to a file, and then you can load it up any device and replay the camera and controller pose and events without needing a headset. Project is led by Diego:

- https://github.com/dmarcos/aframe-motion-capture
- http://swimminglessonsformodernlife.com/aframe-motion-capture/examples/

This will become the common way to develop for VR without having to enter and re-enter VR to test each code change, and to do it on the go